# Help with using monostable one-shot multivibrator for limited time

Tags: timer, 555, monostable, debouncing, switch-debouncing

Trying to develop a circuit that would know how to output a square wave with a duty cycle that would be controllable, and the duration would be between half a second and a second.
Now I manage to make the circuit using a microcontroller that produces these pulses, but I wanted a solution that is only analog, I thought about the 555 timer idea, but I can't find a way to detect a falling edge, and that each falling will produce a number of limited pulses,
And when the VIN/TRIGGER is at a logical '1', the output will also be a '1', and only when someone released the button (a button is basically equal to a logical '1') then the circuit will output a square wave.
Is it even possible to do this with a 555 and another circuit? Or only through a microcontroller?
Attach the requested waveform
[image]

Comment: The fact that you need to stop the pulses after some time basically forces you to combine two 555s, and at that point I'm really not sure whether you're doing yourself and favor not using a microcontroller. Sounds like the kind of problem that MCUs were invented for.